# How can I update an information in Firestore with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
   TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Map<String, String> save = {'description': controller.text};
                  final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('profiles')
                      .doc('8hhVmOL9OmoalaWb5ico');
                      
                    docUser.update(save);

                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Save'))
```

The code here works flawlessly and finds the 'description' property in the relevant 'doc-id' and adds the value I wrote next to it. But I don't want to do this data update process according to a certain 'doc-id'. The user already creates an id in the firestore while registering, and I added this id to the user's database. Based on this id property, I want to update the 'description' property of the person who has the id.

```
    class Profiles {
  String id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String gender;
  final String email;
  final String description;

  Profiles(
      {required this.id,
      required this.email,
      required this.gender,
      required this.name,
      required this.username,
      required this.description});

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'id': id,
        'name': name,
        'gender': gender,
        'email': email,
        'username': username,
        'description': description
      };

  static Profiles fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Profiles(
        id: json['id'],
        email: json['email'],
        gender: json['gender'],
        name: json['name'],
        username: json['username'],
        description: json['description'],
      );
}
```

Here you can see what features have been added to Firestore while a user is registering. If I can get the id attribute of each user and make a match accordingly, I can change the 'description' attribute of whoever the id belongs to. But I couldn't find how to do this.

Comment: This is a noop: `docUser.update();`. Did you mean to pass the map to it: `docUser.update(save);`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to write it while making changes to the code. I edited.

Comment: "The user already creates an id in the firestore while registering, and I added this id to the user's database." Can you show the code that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance for the current user:

```
User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

You can use it in your function:

```
   TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                  Map<String, String> save = {'description': controller.text};
                  final docUser = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('profiles')
                      .doc(user!.id);
                      
                    docUser.update(save);

                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Save'))
```